# Collection addFieldToFilter does not filtering

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I have a NON-EAV model, and I want to filter on its collection like below

```
$td_trans_collection = Mage::getModel('tichdiem/scoretransaction')->getCollection();        
$td_trans_collection->addFieldToFilter('increment_id', $incrementId)
                    ->addFieldToFilter('action', self::TICHDIEM_ADD)
                    ->load();
```

The query produce by

```
 $td_trans_collection->getSelect()->__toString();
```

return

```
 SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `fhs_td_score_transaction` AS `main_table` WHERE (increment_id = '100010565') AND (action = '0')
```

which is a correct query, should return only 1 answer. I ran this query on the terminal as well. However, when I loop through the collection like

```
 foreach($td_trans_collection as $item){
     echo $item;
 }
```

I got every entries inside my table, why is this the case? I am using Magento 1.9.1

Comment: Why don't use getFirstItem() instead of load() if you should get only one row? You would not have to loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, test that select query directly in your database to see what it returns. If it's returning only one row as you want then that means somewhere in Magento, something is modifying your collection perhaps.

Alternatively, you can try this method to limit your collection to 1 result:

```
$td_trans_collection->getSelect()->limit(1);
```

You can also try:

```
$td_trans_collection->getFirstItem()->getData();
```

If that reliably returns the result you want, then problem solved.

If the above fails, go to: lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php and locate the following properties and change them as shown below:

```
protected $_debug               = true;
protected $_logAllQueries       = true;
```

After you set those values to true, run your collection again. Then go to: var/debug/pdo_mysql.log and take a careful look at the final queries that were executed. Hopefully, this will give you a better clue as to what's happening.

Additionally, remove the `->load();`

Comment: `$td_trans_collection->getData()` return the correct item in the table that I wanted, however, it returned in the format of array instead of Object. I know now that I at least have 1 backup solution. The query is run correctly on the database terminal, it is only the collection that return every entries in my table. I will try to use `$_debug` and `$_logAllQueries` to see if I can spot anything wrong

Comment: ->getData() always returns as an array. Just remove getData() and it will be an object

Comment: @ThangPham Did this answer work for you? If so, please mark it as accepted so that I can get credit for it. Better late than never. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't call load(), you will retrieve everything again, when you already have that in the collection object. The collection is an associative array, add

Answer (score 0):

If you claim that your query returns 1 record.

The correct way to loop through the collection is

```
foreach($td_trans_collection as $item){
var_dump($item->getData());
}
```

Comment: Please read my question again, I have the exact loop as you provided here. It show records of the entire table.

Comment: to get the value of a particular row for eg, increment_id, you can use $item->getIncrementId(). By default, collection renders all the records of the table.